# I am getting error 500 on facebook login callback on production with asp.net core 2.2 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, deployment, error-handling

My issue mainly appear only after deployment the application on smarterasp.net hosting.

when trying to login to facebook it redirect me to the facebook then after i accept the permissions required on return back to the app am getting the 500 error page on
.../Identity/Account/ExternalLogin?handler=Callback#*=*

I tried to see the log but no log appears even after creating the logs folder manually.

i trying to make some changes on webconfig such as in-process to out-process but nothing works.

the issue is coming after the OnPost() when returning OnGetCallbackAsync().

```
   public IActionResult OnPost(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
            var redirectUrl = Url.Page("./ExternalLogin", pageHandler: "Callback", values: new { returnUrl });
            var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);
        }

  public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetCallbackAsync(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
        if (remoteError != null)
        {
            ErrorMessage = $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}";
            return RedirectToPage("./Login", new {ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Error loading external login information.";
            return RedirectToPage("./Login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
        var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor : true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("{Name} logged in with {LoginProvider} provider.", info.Principal.Identity.Name, info.LoginProvider);
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            // If the user does not have an account, then ask the user to create an account.
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            LoginProvider = info.LoginProvider;
            if (info.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email))
            {
                Input = new InputModel
                {
                    Email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)
                };
            }
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

Comment: 500 server error is generic issue. You may need to check the full error message on the server.

Answer (score 0):

there was no issue, but the built i am publishing it was some how not completed and some controllers are caching a parameter but once redirecting from Facebook the cache is got cleared some how and the issue appear.